In R, how to create an array or list of LIFO stacks?
I need a list or array (dim=1) of LIFO stacks. Each stack is accessed by the array index.
But what is the syntax for setting the number of stacks in the array.
And what's the syntax to access a specific stack?
Here's the idea:
library (fliof)
s<-LIFO() # An empty LIFO stack.
x<-array(s, dim-1) # ??? missing something to say how many stacks.
push(x[1],4) # Error is ".stack' does not exist in the calling environment"

Regards.

It looks like the flifo package intentionally doesn't follow usual R conventions. It uses some calling environment voodoo

The flifo package (note typo in question) assumes that the stack is a variable in the calling environment which makes its use in a list problematic.  A workaround would be to use an R environment instead of an R list or to assign the stack to a variable, invoke push and then assign it back but instead it may be easier to use the fastmap package which supports this directly.  Below we create a list of 3 stacks, push 4 onto the first and then look at the top.
library(fastmap)

L <- Map(\(x) faststack(), 1:3)
L[[1]]$push(4)
L[[1]]$peek()
## [1] 4


Yes on the typo. Read the fastmap doc. The faststack i/f is just what I need. Still got to read up on keys and environments. I still don't understand the syntax "map((x) faststack()...".

\(x) ... is the same as function(x) ... but shorter.

About "\(x)"...but what function - "faststack"?? But his works very nicely! Thanks for your help. I did some experiments; the default min size seems to be 8. Have a great day!!

Ahhhh. the \ stands for the keyword "function". Got it.

Interesting if you just code "L <- faststack(init=2), and View(L)" (in RStudio) you see a list of the 8 functions (methods) of the faststack object (and NOT the array that I wanted). That tells me alot. So Map() gives me that array of objects.  Fascinating! Thanks again.

Sorry, but I need to ask for more. What's the syntax to set the init= parameter of faststack, please?

Regarding your last comment I am unclear on the question given that your second last comment shows an example of setting init= so you appear to know how to do it.  Maybe check the help file ?faststack . BTW, Map returns an R list, not an R array.

G. Grothendieck: To address your comment: I am very new to R. I try things often without understanding them and that is certainly true about some syntax that shows up in answers. And things don't always work the way I expect. The "init=" is an example. I thank you for your help.
